# Table1 package gives error message "could not find function "isFALSE" "

Tags: r

Trying to recreate the example from [this post](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html), using the table1 package in R:

```
library(boot) 

melanoma2 <- melanoma
 
melanoma2$status <- 
  factor(melanoma2$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))

table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, data=melanoma2)
```

However, I receive the error message

> Error in ifelse(x >= 10^digits & isFALSE(round.integers), formatC(round(x), : could not find function "isFALSE"

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Could you share the output of ``sessionInfo()`` in your main question.

Comment: the code does not give me any errors, did you install and load the package 'table1'?

Comment: `isFALSE` appeared in R 3.5.0, see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.5.0/NEWS.R-3.5.0.html

Comment: Indeed @Victorp , the solution was to update my release of R to the latest version. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the problem has been taken into account, if you install from GitHub, it should work with R < 3.5 (https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1)